# React Native- Touchable not working and no errors?

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to detect touch on a view in React Native. I followed this [link](https://reactnative.dev/docs/handling-touches)  and incorporated the Touchable around my styled view like so:

```
<TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={cardPressed}>
       <View style={styles.card}>
          <Text style={styles.card_Head}>What is Something?</Text>
          <Text style={styles.card_Body}>Something</Text>
       </View>
</TouchableWithoutFeedback>
```

I am using a functional component, so after `export default function App() {` I have:

```
function cardPressed()
    {
      console.log('pressed');
    }
```

No errors, but I get nothing. What is wrong w this implementation?

Comment: I test your code on [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vigorous-river-pmc3z?file=/src/App.js), but it work?  it console out the `pressed` ..  is it you put the function in wrong place or something else

Comment: I also test your code but it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this code.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { StyleSheet, TouchableWithoutFeedback, Text, View } from "react-native";

const App = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  const cardPressed = () => {
     console.log('pressed');
     setCount(count + 1);
  };
 
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.countContainer}>
        <Text style={styles.countText}>Count: {count}</Text>
      </View>
      
      <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={cardPressed}>
        <View style={styles.button}>
          <Text style={styles.card_Head}>What is Something?</Text>
          <Text style={styles.card_Body}>Something</Text>
        </View>
      </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "center",
    paddingHorizontal: 10
  },
  button: {
    alignItems: "center",
    backgroundColor: "#DDDDDD",
    padding: 10
  },
  countContainer: {
    alignItems: "center",
    padding: 10
  },
  countText: {
    color: "#FF00FF"
  },
  card_Head: {
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    fontSize: 24
  },
  card_Body: {
    fontStyle: 'italic'
  }
});

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

Check your import. You should import TouchableWithoutFeedback from react-native and not from react-native-gesture-handler